# forcing open graph video (og:video) content to display as clickable image still in feed

Tags: video, facebook-graph-api, feed, facebook-opengraph

Is there a way to set og:video or one of its meta values so that it displays in feeds as an image link back to the originating URL rather than as an embedded video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you want a link back to your site, don't include the og:video tag in your OG markup.

Omitting an og:video tag means your link will render as a standard stream story, with a title, image and description. Clicking on this will link back to your site.

Answer (score 0):

Per Facebook's own documentation on meta tag og:video:type, found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/video/:

"There are two valid types: "application/x-shockwave-flash" - specifying this will allow us to to play the video in the feed; "text/html" - we just link out to the URL in og:video if this type is specified."

So specifying your type as "text/html" should maintain the video object in your stream story (and not have it just be called a link share) while still forcing the click-thru rather than inline playback.

Answer (score 0):

Using text/html doesn't work for me. Even then, facebook will try to embed the video and play the video inline rather than linking back to your site.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/227447500715941

Comment: Have you found a way to share in Facebook an iframe instead of the video element? I'm using the og:video:type as "text/html" and the og:type with "my_namespace:object_type" with an object I created in the app's open graph settings but no luck. My post content is being added as a video element instead of an iframe. Do I need to submit my app for review or whitelisting?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like facebook only accept application/x-shockwave-flash or video/mp4.

> MIME type of the video. Either application/x-shockwave-flash or video/mp4.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters